# C#/.xaml Having problem with WPF pages, grid vertical expansion

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, controls

So here's my problem, when I expand the main window the pages presenter frame seems to expand too but only horizontaly.  (see photo #1) The 5 buttons on the bottom stay at the original resolution position verticaly but expand horizontaly, I've put them between stars related columns and rows. It worked well for my wlecome pages an this methos seems to work horizontaly. I'm wonderind if the problem comes from previoulsy setuped proprieties.  Problem is related to fifthline but can be post problems.

**Images**

====================================

[Original size see 2 border buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzy0e.png)

[Expanded window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuvJR.png)

[Grid setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkvEs.png)

[Expand working on homepage *Grid setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxaJt.jpg)

====================================

```
    <Border Padding="1">

    <StackPanel>

        <!---FirstLine-->

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="445"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="365"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="390"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="28"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock  Text="Prénom" Margin="30,5,165,0" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Black"/>
            <TextBox    Name="ClientPage_BoxPrenom" Text="Jean" Margin="100,-1,5,1" Padding="0,5" FontSize="12"/>
            <TextBlock  Text="Nom" Margin="5,4,245,1" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Black"/>
            <TextBox    Name="ClientPage_BoxNom" Text="Dujardins" Margin="60,-1,0,1" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0,5"/>

        </Grid>

        <!---SecondLine-->

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="433"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="472"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="275"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="46"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>



            <TextBlock  Text="Ville" Margin="30,20,0,0" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Black"/>
            <ComboBox   Name="ClientPage_ComboVille" Margin="100,20,0,0" Padding="0,5" FontSize="12"/>
            <CheckBox   Name="ClientPage_CehckResponsable" Content="Responsable" Margin="10,25,361,0" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Medium"/>

        </Grid>

        <!---ThirdLine-->

        <Grid Height="79">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="393"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="787"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="74"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock  Text="Membre depuis:" Margin="30,50,0,0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <DatePicker Name="ClientPage_DatepickDatedebut" Text="Membre depuis:" Margin="130,50,770,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

        </Grid>

        <!---FourthLine-->

        <Grid Height="191">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="217"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="373"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="590"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="191"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <GroupBox Name="ClientPage_GroupExp" Header="Années d'expériences" Margin="14,12,6,8" Grid.Column="0">
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,-2,0">
                    <RadioButton Content="Moins d'un an" Margin="50,10,0,10"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="1 à 4 ans" Margin="50,10,0,10"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="5 à 9 ans" Margin="50,10,0,10"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="10 ans et plus" Margin="50,10,0,10"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
            <ListBox Name="ClientPage_List" Margin="26,22,144,8" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Button x:Name="ClientPage_Buttonnouveau_Copy1" Content="OriginalFrame&#xD;&#xA;Top right" Grid.Column="2" Margin="471,-150,-1,287" Click="ClientPage_Buttonnouveau_Copy1_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="ClientPage_Buttonnouveau_Copy" Content="OriginalFrame&#xD;&#xA;Bottom Left" Margin="3,617,94,-480" Click="ClientPage_Buttonnouveau_Copy1_Click" />



        <!---FifthLine-->
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="484">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="149*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="227*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="63*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="433*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="251*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="64"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <Button x:Name="ClientPage_Buttoneffacer" Content="Effacer" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,4" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Button x:Name="ClientPage_Buttonprecedent" Content="&lt;--"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,0,2,4" />
            <Button x:Name="ClientPage_Buttonesuivant" Content="--&gt;"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Margin="0,0,1,4" />
            <Button x:Name="ClientPage_Buttonajouter" Content="Ajouter"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="6" Margin="0,0,2,4" />
            <Button x:Name="ClientPage_Buttonnouveau" Content="Nouveau" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="7" Margin="0,0,0,4" />



        </Grid>





    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you have is that you're using a `StackPanel` for your root layout panel. This is preventing your layout from expanding vertically.

You might want to consider using a `Grid` or a `DockPanel` instead.

Comment: Thanks man its also what i thaught but i wanted to be sure and not having to re-do everything ;) so dock panel will expand grids around them ?

Comment: This is what their description of the difference between them mean with sharable and un-sharable items ?

Comment: So ill put a main grid and stack panel into them TYVM